# Cant import without value into phpmyadmin on IIS8 Webserver

Tags: mysql

I have troubles with inserting data into database. In localhost everything was working, but after moving it on windows server 2012 I can't insert data from website into database, when there is no value from input. 
Input is normal

```
div>Service ID: </div>
        <div><input type="text" id="service_id" name="service_id value="" />
```

Insert :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations (name, start, end,..,partners_id) 
VALUES (:name, :start, :end, ..., :partners_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $_POST['start']);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $_POST['end']);

// I am using this: if value is empty to put own value, but I would like to not use it
$stmt->bindParam(':partners_id',empty($_POST['partners_id'])?'9999' :$_POST['partners_id']);
```

Do you know about anything? Like setting something in database? because sometimes, you don't have to fill few inputs..and I don't get it why it is working perfectly on localhost, but on windows server I have this problem

I am using php 5.6, MySql 5.5 and phpmyadmin 4.6.4

Thank you

Comment: when I try to import few data into new table..I found that this fucntion is causing problem. $stmt->bindParam(':partners_id',empty($_POST['partners_id'])?'9999' :$_POST['partners_id']);      ....especially this part : empty($_POST['partners_id']) ? '9999' :  ..does anyone know to write it different?

Comment: And I have another php file which is updating values..and I am not using this empty "function" and its not working also ..

Comment: Do you `execute()` $stmt? bingParam just binds the parameters and you still have to execute the query.

Comment: Is the missing `"` in your html just a typo here, or is that your actual html code? And note that the windows version has NOTHING to do with this problem. You're not doing anything OS-specific with this code. What DOES matter is the PHP version. You probably will not be able to bind to a function call RESULT in newer PHP versions.

Comment: @Isaac Yes I use execute();

Comment: @Marc It is just typo.